# Android custom keyboard with 2 lablels (main and small at the top right)

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I am implementing my own custom keyboard.

I use [this tutorial](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) for implementing keyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <Row>
    <Key android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:keyLabel="w"/>
    <Key android:keyLabel="e"/>
    <Key android:keyLabel="r"/>
    <Key android:keyLabel="t"/>
    <Key android:keyLabel="y"/>
    <Key android:keyLabel="u"/>
    <Key android:keyLabel="i"/>
    <Key android:keyLabel="o"/>
    <Key android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
```

I want have 2 label on key button.The same as on image below (red):

[image]

How can I change the keyboard xml to have this? When we make the long click on button we should choose numbers instead of letters

Comment: you can not force to user to use custom keyboard.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I want know how can I have 2 letters (main and small (red color))

Comment: hi @Tim i also stuck on same problem you are facing....have you solved this problem....

Comment: below there is a good answer. But I used widgets Buttons on my own layout. I don't have many buttons, so it is ok for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to create a KeyboardView extends class and override OnDraw method like this:

```
public class MKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(15);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for(Key key: keys) {
        if(key.codes[0] == 113)
            canvas.drawText("1", key.x + (key.width/2), key.y + 25, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

you can change the position by changing the x and y parameters.

enjoy :)

Comment: Hi @Yakov can you help me to solve this problem,                      I am getting NullPointerException when my control reaches at below line, canvas.drawText("1", key.x + (key.width/2), key.y + 25, paint);