# Soft Keyboard getting NullPointerException when calling canvas.drawtext

Tags: key, label, android-softkeyboard, multiline

> I am working on SoftKeyboard where i need to display text on keys as
>   shown below by red blocks

[image]

As given [in this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738452/android-custom-keyboard-with-2-lablels-main-and-small-at-the-top-right) and [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000543/customize-the-appearance-of-a-key), I am using below code,

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (canvas != null) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(15);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        int x2 = 0;
        int y2 = 0;
        int width = 0;
        List<Key> keys = SoftKeyboard.currentKeyboard.getKeys();
        for(Key key: keys) {
        if(key.codes[0] == 113)
            x2 = key.x; // value of x2 = 0;
            y2 = key.y; // value of y2 = 0;
            width = key.width; // value of width = 32;
            canvas.drawText("1", x2 + (width/2), y2 + 5, paint); // getting null pointer exception here line 240
        }
    }
```

> My stack trace is shown below
>
> **> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.example.android.softkeyboard.CandidateView.onDraw(CandidateView.java:240)
>   at
>   com.example.android.softkeyboard.CandidateView.setSuggestions(CandidateView.java:279)
>   at
>   com.example.android.softkeyboard.SoftKeyboard.setSuggestions(SoftKeyboard.java:597)
>   at
>   com.example.android.softkeyboard.SoftKeyboard.updateCandidates(SoftKeyboard.java:582)
>   at
>   com.example.android.softkeyboard.SoftKeyboard.onFinishInput(SoftKeyboard.java:260)
>   at
>   android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.doFinishInput(InputMethodService.java:1543)
>   at
>   android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.doStartInput(InputMethodService.java:1552)
>   at
>   android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.startInput(InputMethodService.java:390)
>   at
>   android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:158)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-19 13:26:04.844:
>   E/Trace(17693): error opening trace file: No such file or directory
>   (2)**
>
> I have checked when i am debugging code the canvas is always null, so
>   I think i am getting this exception due to canvas is null.
>
> So i am getting this exception due to canvas is null or problem lies
>   anywhere else.
>
> And one thing more i have also tried using popupCharacters and this
>   is working but i need 3 characters on key as shown below,

[image]

> That's why i am trying to do with paint on canvas but getting
>   exception.

Comment: This Exception happens exactly because canvas is null. I don't see a reason why it should be null in the onDraw method unless the method is called with a null argument, so you should next try to figure out why it's called with a null canvas. Could you post CandidateView.setSuggestions next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **mistake** i am **extending View class** in my class. So then i **extended KeyboardView** as i working with **LatinKeyboard** which solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly `canvas` is being passed as null.  The problem is where the function you posted is getting called from.  This is potentially also causing you problems:

```
if (canvas != null) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

You avoid calling the parent if canvas is null, but you don't handle the rest of your code differently?  At the very least, I would put the rest of your code *inside* this conditional block and when canvas is null allow nothing to happen.

Comment: Thanks for reply...i know that i am passing null value that's why it giving me nullPointerException. So i posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**NO need to draw it**,There is simple way of achieving this .. [See detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752580/creating-a-softkeyboard-with-multiple-alternate-characters-per-key?rq=1).